# Visio 2016 is not showing pages on the bottom and unable to navigate around pages

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2016

Visio 2016 is not showing pages on the bottom and unable to navigate around pages.
Visio 2016 file is saved as a GROUP name and missing the page tab at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

The file has got itself stuck in group edit mode.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/visio-2016-stuck-in-group-showing-a-single-shape/d39c7d1e-6da6-41a4-a534-7aff55f43b35?auth=1

or

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c66779ad-8756-4a80-89de-97c5daa736cb/visio-weird-mode-2007?forum=visiogeneral

Comment: P.S. This is valid for all versions of Visio, not just Visio 2016.